# Extract coordinates form UCSC names

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a string like:

hg38_ct_tbrefGene_6787_NM_000029_1_range=chr1:230709995-230710853_5'pad=0_3'pad=0_strand=-_repeatMasking=none

I would like to extract the coordinates, in the above example: 230709995 and 230710853. I have to mention that the previous part of the string does not have always the same length. I guess `gsub` is the best option but I cannot manage to get them (too many "_").

Additionally, a suggestion of pattern matching cheatsheet/book/blog for this kind of problems would be great!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use regex and capturing groups for this purpose. For more information simply search the web for "regex" or "regular expression" and you will find several sites that will guide you how to set up flexible search and extraction patterns. Below extraction for your string works as follows (I assume that the coordinates are always preceeded by the word *range*). As an alternative to gsub you might also use, e.g., `stri_extract` from `stringi` package.

Search for capturing groups (the content within parenthesis):
`(^.*)`  start of the string followed by any character zero or more times
`(range.*:)` *range* followed by any character zero or more times followed by a colon *:*
`(\\d+)` one or more digits
`(\\D)` one non digit character
`(\\d+)` one or more digits
`(.*$)` any character zero or more times until the end of the string

Extract:
`\\3` capturing group 3, i.e., the first `(\\d+)`
`\\5` capturing group 5, i.e., the second `(\\d+)`

```
string <- "hg38_ct_tbrefGene_6787_NM_000029_1_range=chr1:230709995-230710853_5'pad=0_3'pad=0_strand=-_repeatMasking=none"

strsplit(gsub("(^.*)(range.*:)(\\d+)(\\D)(\\d+)(.*$)", "\\3 \\5", string , perl = TRUE), " ")
# [[1]]
# [1] "230709995" "230710853"
```